# SQL Server Management Studio can not connect

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 2014. In "connect to server" window, I selected server type as "Database engine", server name as "(local)" but when I try to connect, n error is shown-

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to ..
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Please help what to do...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

This is a common error which arises when connecting to SQL Server with Management Studio.

This includes different type of error scenarios like (Service--Not Available),(Service-Not Running),(Network Library- Not Enabled),(Fire Wall-Blocking) Etc.

Please troubleshoot in systematic manner.

1. Click On start button and type `Services.MSC`
2. Check whether the SQL Server service has been installed and is running fine.

Please check the service whether started or not.

If Yes:

- Next Scenario is Network Libraries Tune.

If No

- Install the SQL Server Engine from the software package and start the service.

Answer (score 7):

Please ensure these configurations status are active

Right Click on the Instance and Start it

[image]

Comment: When I click SQL Server Services, nothing shows in the right side window, "There are no items to show in this view." this message is shown. Please help---

Comment: Did you install SQL Server with management studio or is it just a SQL Management Studio?

Comment: I probably havent installed SQL Server on the system.

Comment: yes, chances are,, if you install when you continue the installation you would be asked SQL Instance name,Password blah blah..

Comment: Now don't run back and download whole SQL Studio with SQL Server. there is a Small Package (SQL only) just about 200MB so just select & download. do the proper installations then it will show in the Instance List

Comment: Why negative vote? please explain before put negatives. will be helpful to understand if there is fault

Answer (score 1):

All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> SQL Server Services, and check if SQL Server service status is “Running”.

Comment: When I click SQL Server Services, the message shows- "There are no items to show in this view."

Comment: Try to reinstall it or to install a new instance of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

1. All Programs
2. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
3. Configuration Tool
4. SQL Server Configuration Manager
5. A pop up will open click on yes
6. Select Sql Server Services (At left side) and Make sure
       Status is running for all services (At right Side)

[reference](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331#sthash.kzSfADZL.dpuf)

Answer (score 0):

in the login screen
Server name: Browse for more -- expand database Engine and choose your database then login again.