# Cannot connect to server - SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql, database-connection, ssms

I'm quite a newbie, just trying to learn some new things. I've recently started learning c# etc and I'd also like to create a new SQL Server database using SQL Server Management Studio.

The thing is that for some reason I am not able to connect to the server. I might have done something wrong (or haven't done something that I should have done). Been researching the problem a lot on google and I found some tips but I still can't make it work.

I even found some installation tutorial in here: http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2014_0005.htm  and I only noticed that I used some different options (I used default, didn't change anything) like for example in "Database Engine Config" I chose "Windows authentication mode".

So that's what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfkyW.jpg

Also I think I may have some problem with services, because when I go to the server configuration manager, the list is completely empty.

Thanks for any tips. If I don't solve this, I can always uninstall SQL Server Management Studio and reinstall it - this time following the steps in the tutorial. Hopefully that wont be necessary so help me please:)!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Did you intentionally select a non-english installation?

Comment: it says that theres an error with connecting to the server. server cannot be found or its unavailable and that i should check if the instance name is correct and check the server config.

Comment: i think the whole management studio is in english, its just this error message thats non-eng

Comment: What is it that you've installed.  Is it just management studio or the server as well? Did the server exist before and can you connect to it from somewhere else?

Comment: well i think i just found (i must have missed it earlier) the same problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851795/sql-server-management-studio-can-not-connect  and yeah well i think i havent installed something. When i run Services.msc i only have this "SQL Server VSS Writer" working. Should i have anything else? What im trying to do is just to connect to the computer im using now. But i tried the name of the computer, tried "localhost", even tried "." and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you install the **Management Studio** only?? That's just the **admin GUI** - but **NOT** the actual database engine!! You need to install either **SQL Server Express** or **SQL Server EXpress with tools** - that's the engine (with or without the mgmt GUI) - otherwise you have only the management GUI, but no database engine to work with!

Comment: I think you might have installed only the client tools.  I'm not so sure it will let you install the enterprise edition server on a non-server operating system.  You could check the services to see if sql server and sql server agent are running.  If you're just learning I would download sql server 2014 express.

Comment: During the installation did it ask for things like server name and whether you wanted windows/sql/mixed authentication?

Comment: what I have is SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. Is it enough or I still need to download something more? If its enough, what would you suggest doing now? Im not sure why there's an empty list when I go to the Server Configuration Manager. Everywhere people advice to check if services are running, but there are no services at all.

Comment: yes it did ask for that

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366339.aspx

Comment: What OS have you installed it on?

Comment: yeah thats the problem, look: http://imgur.com/DtRjN7Z  they say i should have some services listed there and start them, but the list it empty. Does it mean that the engine hasnt been installed? 
The OS is win 8.1

Comment: Sorry, I've just he image properly, I can see you're using Windows 8.  I couldn't see it properly before I'm using the mobile version of the app.

Comment: I think all you've got installed is Management studio and not the database engine.  Can you give me the URL of where you downloaded the installation?

Comment: yeah i think that might me the problem. Well i downloaded it through dreamspark (Microsoft's platform for students so they can have some software for free). I'll try downloading just SQL Server 2014 this time, not just the management studio ;)

Comment: I've had a look at the link you posted about the installation instructions.  As I mentioned before SQL server enterprise (database engine) won't install on a non-Server OS, You'll need at least Windows Server 2008.  Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx for the system requirements.  During the installation there must have been an option to install the database engine, but it was probably disabled because of your OS.

Comment: I suggest you uninstall 2014 Enterprise and download SQL Server 2014 express http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42299 and make sure you select database engine as part of the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look at the link you posted about the installation instructions. As I mentioned before SQL server enterprise (database engine) won't install on a non-Server OS, You'll need at least Windows Server 2008. Have a look at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx for the system requirements. During the installation there must have been an option to install the database engine, but it was probably disabled because of your OS.

I suggest you uninstall 2014 Enterprise and download SQL Server 2014 express microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42299 and make sure you select database engine as part of the installation.

Comment: just finished installing SQL Server 2014 Express and Management Studio and it works perfect now ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get into SQL, I would suggest trying out [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) first. I've utilized it a little bit and found it to be fairly simple with a decent amount of documentation. This version of SQL will still function with various languages. It doesn't utilize Windows authentication, but rather lets you set a root password specific to the database itself. I don't know if your software is similar to that but there may be an option to not use Windows authentication and instead authenticate within the database software itself.