# SQL Server 2014 cannot connect to local database server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2008 and 2014 installed. I am able to connect to SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2014 local instances using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. But when using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, I get the following error:

> Connect to Server
>   Cannot connect to LOCAL\SQL2014.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=18016;
>   handshake=14215;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

I get the same error when I try to setup a new connection in Visual Studio 2015 using the `Entity Data Model Wizard`.

**Updated:**
I found that it connects if I put my ip address or ::1 in place of my machine name.  I also did try 127.0.0.1 for the server name and I get the following message:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.

So, my question is why will it not connect when using my machine name like it does when I use sql server management studio 2008.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851795/sql-server-management-studio-can-not-connect

Comment: The error in that suggested stackoverflow question is not the same that I am getting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the local machine and the `SQL2014` instance, try using either

```
(local)\SQL2014
```

(*note the parenthesis!*), or

```
.\SQL2014
```

as your server/instance name.

Comment: In my post I had removed the machine name and just put "local" in place of the path.  But I did try what you suggested and I get the same error.